# Check if class $PSPACE$ is closed under polyonomially space reduction

Tags: complexity-theory

> Check if class $PSPACE$ is closed under polyonomially space reduction

Any ideas ? It is fairly difficult to prove it, because I don't understand exactly what it does mean that problems are closed under space reduction.

Comment: It's impossible to prove something unless you know what you're supposed to prove... So a good first step will be to figure out what it means for a class to be closed under polynomial space reductions. Presumably this was explained in class.

Comment: If question asked about log-space reduction, this would be hard. But it is not hard at all from definitions of poly-space reduction and PSPACE. Check them.

Comment: The answer is yes, ok ?\

Comment: I hope you understand why it is.